# Entity Framework Code First ForeignKey Unsigned Int (10) MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, code-first, unsigned-integer

I have MySQL database mapped to Code First Entities in EF6, the Foreign keys works for me with [ForeignKey] DataAnnotation but is not working with the keys that are defined in MySQL with unsigned int (10).

I'm having a DBUpdateException with the message in the inner exception "Unknown Column 'T_USER_OID' in 'field list'.

I have this key mapped as long in C#.

This field is not defined in both (MySQL Database and Entities model). I think that EF is not recognizing well the ForeignKey defined using DataAnnotations but I'm only having this problem with this DataType keys.

Comment: T_USER_OID is not a field in my Code First entities. I think that this name is automatically asigned by EF when it tries to map the defined ForeignKey in my Entity.

Comment: After too much time trying to solve the problem I have discovered that the problem is One To Many Relation Ships.
After solving the problem I have another problem that I have asked here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611449/ef6-codefirst-one-to-many-mysql-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails