# EF6 CodeFirst One to Many MySQL a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm doing a Mapping from existing Database to CodeFirst and I'm having a problem with One To Many Relationships.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity. Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails

I have a T_USER entity like this.

```
public partial class T_USER{

    public T_USER(){
        this.T_OBJECTS = new HashSet<T_OBJECTS> ();
        this.T_OBJECTS1 = new HashSet<T_OBJECTS> ();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection <T_OBJECT> T_OBJECTS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection <T_OBJECT> T_OBJECTS1 { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have my T_OBJECT entity like this.

```
public partial class T_OBJECT (){

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int USER1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int USER2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("USER1")]
    public virtual T_USER T_USER1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("USER2")]
    public virtual T_USER T_USER2 { get; set; }
}
```

With this DataAnnotations I have a DBUpdateException "Unknown Column T_USER_OID in field list"

I have discovered that if my Database field names doesn't follow the Code First Conventions I have to use the Fluent API for One To Many Relationships and I have coded like this.

```
public class T_OBJECT_Map : EntityTypeConfiguration <T_OBJECTS>
    {
        public T_OBJECT_Map()
        {
            this.HasRequired<T_USER>(M => M.T_USER)
                .WithMany(U => U.T_OBJECTS)
                .HasForeignKey(M => M.USER1);

            this.HasRequired<T_USER>(M => M.T_USER1)
                .WithMany(U => U.T_OBJECTS1)
                .HasForeignKey(M => M.USER2);
        }
    }
```

With this code I have the exception that I have mentioned at the beginning of this question.

I have also try to set the DBInitializer to null using this code to prevent the EF try to write in the Database but it fails with the same Exception

```
Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
```

Comment: Just a question from someone without much experience with code first. Why use code first if there is already a existing database? Why not generate the models based on the database structure?

Comment: I now that I can use Database First method. But I want to use Code First because I have to work with Oracle and MySQL and Code First is better to avoid regenerating the model. And also I want to migrate to Code First model.